# How I can extract the portion of words from the file using python3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-processing

I want to extract the specific word from the text file.
Here is the example text file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzQ6rtO2VN95d3NrTjktMExfNkU/view?usp=sharing
Kindly review it.
I am trying to extract the string as:

```
"Name": "the name infront of it"
"Link": "Link infront of it"
```

Say from the input file, I am expecting to get output like this:

```
"Name":"JTLnet"
"Link":"http://jtlnet.com"
"Name":"Apache 1.3"
"Link":"http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3"
"Name":"Apache"
"Link":"http://httpd.apache.org/"
.
.
.
"Name":"directNIC"
"Link":"http://directnic.com"
```

If these words are anywhere in the file, it should get extracted to another file.
Kindly let me know how I can achieve this sort of extraction? Kindly consider the file as the small part of big file.
Also, it is text file not json.
Kindly help me.

Comment: it looks very like json, have you tried `json.load` ?

Comment: Yes I did. Didn't work for me. So thought of making the file as text. Is it doable?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Can you help me with it?

Comment: show how should look the expected result, at least for a fragment of your actual file(let's say for the first 5 lines)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest See I have edited my question and now you can see. Can you help me now?

Comment: I suppose, it should extract data from those parts which have `"Categories"` as the first key, right?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Yes you are correct.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest You got it right my friend. Can you help me?

Comment: why didn't json.load work? error? or just not the structure you expected?

Comment: @JafferWilson, I've got the solution, the only nuance is should there be a gap between each of sections started with "Name" ? Or it would be enough to output the list of consecutive lines?

Comment: @Aaron It didn't gave me any output. I tried even have pasted te question here but  got deleted.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Can you please paste the answer so everyone will know.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I didn't understood what you mean by nuance?

Comment: there are typo's in the quoting too... I'd say use regex..

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest You got it wrong. Actually, I just want to show that the name and link sequence continues.. The dot are just to show continuation. I am interested in just getting the Name and link and no description or rest others. Please let me know.

Comment: @Aaron Please let me know how you can achieve it with regex. Actually I am a bit confused with regex usage.

Comment: @JafferWilson see if my answer works for your big file

Comment: @Sriram Perfecto.... Can you please tell me how to write to another file the output that we get

Comment: @JafferWilson see updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short solution using `re.findall()` and `str.split()` functions:

```
import re

with open('test.txt', 'r') as fh:
    p = re.compile(r'(?:"Categories":[^,]+,)("Name":"[^"]+"),(?:[^,]+,)("Link":"[^"]+")')
    result = [pair for l in re.findall(p, fh.read()) for pair in l]

print('\n'.join(result))
```

The output(fragment):

```
"Name":"JTLnet"
"Link":"http://jtlnet.com"
"Name":"Apache 1.3"
"Link":"http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3"
"Name":"Apache"
"Link":"http://httpd.apache.org/"
"Name":"PHP"
....
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the text file is not formatted properly, the only option for you is regex. The below snippet works for the given sample file.

Keep in mind that this requires you to load the entire file into memory

```
import re, json
f = open(r'filepath')
textCorpus = f.read()
f.close()
# replace empty strings to non-empty, match regex easily
textCorpus = textCorpus.replace('""', '" "')
lstMatches = re.findall(r'"Name".+?"Link":".+?"', textCorpus)
with open(r'new_file.txt', 'ab+) as wf:
    for eachMatch in lstMatches:
        convJson = "{" + eachMatch + "}"
        json_data = json.loads(convJson)
        wf.write(json_data["Name"] + "\n")
        wf.write(json_data["Link"] + "\n")
```

Comment: How I can write the output to another file... this is awsome.

Answer (score 1):

Your file is a wrongly formatted json with extraneous double quote. But it is enough for the json module not to be able to load it. You are left with lower level regex parsing.

Assumptions:

- the interesting part after `"Name"` or `"Link"` is:

  - separated from the identifier by a colon (`:`)
  - enclosed in double quotes (`"`) with no included double quote
- the file is structured in lines
- Name and Link fields are always on one single line (no new line in fields)

You can process your file line by line with a simple `re.finditer` on each line:

```
rx = re.compile(r'(("Name":".*?")|("Link":".*?"))')
with open(inputfile) as fd:
    for line in fd:
    l = rx.finditer(line)
        for elt in l:
            print(elt.group(0))
```

If you want to output data to another file, just open it before above snippet with `open(outputfile, "w") as fdout:` and replace the print line with:

```
fdout.write(elt.group(0) + "\n")
```